# read text file and writing to a list

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, split

Is their a way to split a text file in multiple places all at once and save to a list?

I was able to do the split in one place and write to a list like this:

```
var incomplete = File
            .ReadAllLines(path)
            .Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None)[5].Trim())
            .ToList();
```

I would like to split in four locations and then write to a list.

```
var mnbrs = File
            .ReadAllLines(path)
            .Select(a => a.Split('|')[2].Trim())
            .Select(b => b.Split('|')[5].Trim())
            .Select(c => c.Split('|')[6].Trim())
            .Select(d => d.Split('|')[11].Trim())
            .ToList();
```

this gives me error index was outside of bounds of array.

Any help is appreciated.
Am also open to split and read filing in a different manner as well.
I just would like to avoid reading file split once then to list then reading agian and splitting again and doing it four times.

Comment: Can you give an example of your text file?

Comment: I believe you are outside the bounds because each `Select` is working on the result of the previous `Select`.  You can debug this by splitting each `Select` into a separate variable and performing the next function on that created variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do it in two steps. First split, then select the individual columns:

```
File
    .ReadAllLines(path)
    .Select(a => a.Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Select(a => new {
        Column1 = a[2].Trim(),
        Column2 = a[5].Trim(),
        Column3 = a[6].Trim(),
        Column4 = a[11].Trim()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/aNyNT5

Comment: Is their a way to split the data that is in a[5] at the space like split(' ') and save the first part to something and save the other part to another column?

Comment: Sure.  `Column2_Part1 = a[5].Trim().Split(' ')[0], Column2_Part2 = a[5].Trim().Split(' ')[1]`.  Although as you add more complexity, I wouldn't try to always shoehorn it into a single LINQ statement.  This method causes the split to happen twice per row, which is less efficient then doing it all at once in a custom `foreach` loop that accomplishes the same thing.  Also, you may find it helpful to create a custom class with properties `Column1`, `Column2`, etc. for passing this data around between different methods.